# Найти максимальный атрибут jQuery

Tags: jquery, сравнение

Есть ли в jQuery функция, которая бы сравнивала на меньше или больше в значениях атрибутах? Вот такой пример есть:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#" value-id="1">1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" value-id="2">2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" value-id="3"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Возможно ли без цикла найти элемент с самым старшим атрибутом, `value-id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По скольку я знаю, в jQuery нет функции, чтобы найти элемент с максимальным атрибутом. Для этого цикл нужен:

```js
var maxValue = -Infinity, maxElement;
$("a[value-id]").each(function() {
  var element =  $(this), 
      value = +element.attr("value-id");
  if(value > maxValue) {
    maxValue = value;
    maxElement = element;
  }
});

maxElement.css("background-color", "yellow");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#" value-id="1">1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" value-id="2">2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" value-id="3">3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Тоже возможно решить с помощью `Array.prototype.sort`, то есть, сортировать элементы, тогда первый будет максимальным.

```js
var $max = $(Array.prototype.sort.call($("a[value-id]"), function(a, b) {
  return $(b).attr("value-id") - $(a).attr("value-id");
})[0]);
$max.css("background-color", "yellow");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#" value-id="1">1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" value-id="2">2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" value-id="3">3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Хотя именно в этом примере можно решить по проще, так как элементы уже в порядке:

```
$("a[value-id]").last()
```

Comment: Спасибо за пример. Я надеялся что все таки можно.

Comment: @PoyCc Я придумал короче решение, с помощью `Array.prototype.sort`.

Answer (score 2):

Чуть проще:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="stack" data-value="1">1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="stack" data-value="2">2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="stack" data-value="3">3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<script>
    var arr = $('a.stack').map(function(){
        return $(this).data("value");
    }).get();
    console.log(arr);

    var max = Math.max.apply(Math,arr);
    var min = Math.min.apply(Math,arr);

    console.log({
        min:min,
        max:max
    });
</script>
```

*Если не брать во внимание нахождение min/max именно через jQuery*

**UPD1:**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="stack" data-value="1">11</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="stack" data-value="2">2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="stack" data-value="3">10</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<script>
    var arr = $('a.stack').map(function(){
        return parseInt($(this).text());
    }).get();
    console.log(arr);

    var max = Math.max.apply(Math,arr);
    var min = Math.min.apply(Math,arr);

    console.log({
        min:min,
        max:max
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Да, найти максимальное значение довольно просто, а как найти *элемент* с максимальным значением?

Comment: К примеру как в UPD1